# Worksheet_Change Not Firing after Button Click Macro Added to Module

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code (which clears the values in dependent drop downs) in the Sheet2 Code Window

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Update by Extendoffice 2018/06/04
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    End If
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

That code worked fine until I added a Button and the following code (which copies the existing row and inserts the selection into a new row) in Module1.  Now the Button Event works fine but the Change event doesn't seem to ever fire.

```
    Sub AddRow()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long
    With Sheet2
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        NextRow = LastRow + 1
            With .Range("B" & LastRow & ":I" & LastRow)
                  Range("B" & LastRow & ":I" & LastRow).Select
                  Selection.Copy
                  Range("B" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).Select
                  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                  Range("C" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).Select
                  Selection.Clear
            End With
    End With
    End Sub
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Make sure your events aren't disabled - sometimes that can happen.

Comment: Side note: `With .Range("B" & LastRow & ":I" & LastRow)` is never used, should probably be deleted, and then you have some unqualified `Range` calls (no period in front to refer to `With Sheet2`).

Comment: @Tim How do I determine if my events are disabled?

Comment: In the Immediate Window, put `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter to enable events.

Comment: @BigBen / Tim That Solved the Issue, I added the Error Handler After I received an error previously  Thanks!!

Comment: Also worth adding `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit sub` to your event handler since it seems like you only want it to react to single-cell changes